# What is the react-router 1.0 equivalent of 0.13's "getCurrentRoutes"?

Tags: react-router

I've been trying to google and github-search my way to victory but I can't seem to find any documentation that explains how the react-router 0.13 construction

```
var Page = React.createClass({
  ...
  // get the current route's component, for :
  getCurrentPageHandler: function() {
    return this.context.router.getCurrentRoutes()[1].handler;
  },
  ... 
});
```

can be turned into something that react-router 1.0 can do.

The function is used by other parts of the codebase to access the static properties of whatever component is wrapped by the Page component, regardless of whether mounting has happened or not, due to the function kicking in both client-side and during server-rendering (so `this.props.children` can't be used to find out what the Page is wrapping. Trying to access it during server-side runs just gives `null`).

Comment: you probably want to use `location`. What are you trying to get?

Comment: `location` gives you the route as string, but no reference to the actual component/component class that is  bound to that route, which is the thing I actually need.

Comment: can you describe the problem you are trying to solve? maybe then I could tell you how it could be implemented in the 1.0

Comment: I cannot, what's in the post is what we have. This is an inherited project with lots of fairly esoteric things, and I have nowhere near enough familiarity with the codebase to say what the original maintainers' intent was. Instead, right now, what I need is to make `getCurrentPageHandler` simply return the component that belongs to a route, using react-router 1.0

Comment: I'm looking into this once again. will get back to you in a bit

Comment: awesome, thank you so much